# Proper using of question mark (null safety) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Is it equal in flutter null safety?

```
    if(widget.mapPickerController != null){
      widget.mapPickerController!.mapMoving = mapMoving;
      widget.mapPickerController!.mapFinishedMoving = mapFinishedMoving;
    }
```

```
    widget.mapPickerController?.mapMoving = mapMoving;
    widget.mapPickerController?.mapFinishedMoving = mapFinishedMoving;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both versions should end up doing the same thing.  [When null-safety enabled, `?.` short-circuits the rest of the expression](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#smarter-null-aware-methods), so if the receiver is `null`, the rest of the expression (including the right-hand-side of the assignment) won't be evaluated.  You can observe that in the following example:

```dart
class Foo {
  int value = 0;
}

int bar() {
  print('Called bar');
  return 42;
}

void main() {
  Foo? foo = null;
  foo?.value = bar();
}
```

where running it generates no errors and shows that `bar()` is never called.

That said, the second version using `?.` is much less clear (which is evident from the apparent confusion in the several deleted answers) and therefore probably should be avoided.

The best way would be to introduce a local variable:

```dart
final mapPickerController = widget.mapPickerController;
if (mapPickerController != null){
  mapPickerController.mapMoving = mapMoving;
  mapPickerController.mapFinishedMoving = mapFinishedMoving;
}
```

and then you don't need to use the null-assertion operator at all, and it's slightly more efficient since you check for `null` only once.